# Syslog-ng to Syslog-ng over TLS - destination not writing to disk

Tags: ssl, rhel7, syslog-ng

Trying to configure a syslog-ng server to send all of the logs that it receives, to another syslog-ng server over TLS. Both running RHEL 7. Everything seems to be working from an encryption and cert perspective. Not seeing any error messages in the logs, an openssl s_client test connection works successfully, I can see the packets coming in over the port that I'm using for TLS, but nothing is being written to disk on the second syslog-ng server. Here's the summary of the config on the syslog server that I'm trying to send the logs to:

source:

```
source s_encrypted_syslog {
    syslog(ip(0.0.0.0) port(1470) transport("tls")
        tls(key-file("/etc/syslog-ng/key.d/privkey.pem")
        certfile("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d/servercert.pem")
        peer-verify(optional-untrusted) 
        }
#changing to trusted once issue is fixed
```

destination:

```
destination d_syslog_facility_f {
file("/mnt/syslog/$LOGHOST/log/$R_YEAR-$R_MONTH-$R_DAY/$HOST_FROM/$HOST/$FACILITY.log" dir-owner ("syslogng") dir-group("syslogng") owner("syslogng") group("syslogng"));
```

log setting:

```
log { source (s_encrypted_syslog); destination (d_syslog_facility_f); };
```

syslog-ng is currently running as root to rule out permission issues. selinux is currently set to permissive. Tried increasing the verbosity on syslog-ng logs and turned on debugging, but not seeing anything jumping out at me as far as errors or issues go. Also the odd thing is, I have very similar config on the first syslog-ng server and it's receiving and storing logs just fine.

Also, I should note that there could be some small typo's in the config above as I'm not able to copy and paste it. Syslog-ng allows me to start up the service with no errors with the config that I have loaded currently. It's simply not writing the data that it's receiving to the destination that I have specified.

Answer (score 0):

It happens quite often that the packet filter prevents a connection to the syslog port, or in your case port 1470. In that case the server starts up successfully, you might even be able to connect using openssl s_client on the same host, but the client will not be able to establish a connection to the server.

Please check that you can actually connect to the server from the client computer (e.g. via openssl s_client, or at least with something like netcat or telnet).

If the connection works, another issue might be that the client is not routing messages to this encrypted destination. syslog-ng only performs the SSL handshake as messages are being sent. No messages would result in the connection being open but not really exchanging packets on the TCP level.

Couple of troubleshooting tips:

- You can check if there is a connection between the client and the server with  "netstat -antp | grep syslog-ng" on the server or the client. You should see connections in the ESTABLISHED state on both sides of the connection (with local/remote addresses switched of course).
- Check that your packet filter lets port 1470 connections through. You are most likely using iptables, try reviewing your ruleset and see if port 1470 on TCP is allowed to pass in the INPUT chain. You could try adding a "LOG" rule right before the default rule to see if the packets are dropped at that level. If you already have LOG rules, you might check the kernel logs of the server to see if that LOG rule produced any messages.
- You can also confirm if there's traffic with tcpdump on the server (e.g. tcpdump -pen port 1470). If you write the traffic dump to a file (e.g. the -w argument to tcpdump, along with -s 0 to avoid truncation), then this dump file can be analyzed with wireshark to see if the negotiation takes place. You should at the very least see a "Client Hello" and a "Server Hello" packet which are not encrypted at the beginning of the handshake.